# Auto real-time curly braces while typing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Automatic curly braces, the one typing aid I actually like while programming, doesn't work how I would like when using Eclipse: I want the matching brace to appear *when I type the first one*, not when I make a new line from an existing one.

Is there a way to do this? I've looked throughout the preferences in Eclipse as well as various Google/Stack Overflow searches.

Answer (score 1):

This option can be found under `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Typing`. Check the box entitled `Braces`.

[image: Screenshot of Preferences Window]